# Line API might be very slow in google cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I have a line bot in Node being hosted by firebase functions and for some reason sending messages from the bot to the user often takes more than 5 seconds. I am also connecting to the sheets API but I am wondering if anyone has had similar problems or if they might see something in my sample code that is wasting a lot of time.

```
'use strict';

//Sheets dependencies
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const key = require('./key.json');

//functions + line dependencies
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const line = require('@line/bot-sdk');
const config = {
    channelSecret: '$channelSecret', // LINE Developersでの準備②でメモったChannel Secret
    channelAccessToken: '$accessToken' // LINE Developersでの準備②でメモったアクセストークン
};

const app = express();

//initialize sheets auth
const sheetsClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
  ]);


app.post('/webhook', line.middleware(config), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.events);
    Promise
      .all(req.body.events.map(handleEvent))
      .then((result) => res.json(result))
      .catch((result) => console.log('error!!!'));
});

const client = new line.Client(config);

async function handleEvent(event) {

  if (event.type !== 'message' || event.message.type !== 'text') {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }
  
  var message = event.message.text;
  console.log("message recieved " + message);
  // console.log(message.startsWith("!"));

  if(message.startsWith("!")){
    var args = message.split(" ");
    var names = ["@123","@1234","@12345","@123456","@123","@12340","@12345","@123456"];
    if(args[0] == "!names") {
        console.log("args length " + args.length.toString());
        // console.log(args[1]);
        //give 5 names
        //cant return more than 10 names in
        if(args.length > 1) {
            if(parseInt(args[1]) != NaN) {
                var numOfNames = parseInt(args[1]);
                if(numOfNames > 0 && numOfNames <= 10) {
                    //check if theres enough names
                    if (numOfNames > names.length) return client.replyMessage(event.replyToken, {
                        type: 'text',
                        text: `Don't have enough names! (${names.length.toString()})`
                    });
                        //send push messages
                    console.log(event);
                    console.log(event.source);
                    for(var i = 0; i<numOfNames; i++) {
                        client.pushMessage(event.source['userId'], {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: names[0]
                        });
                        names.shift();
                    }   
                    
                }
            }
        } else {
            //if arg length is not > 1
            return client.replyMessage(event.replyToken, {
                type: 'text',
                text: event.message.text + 'を受け取りました。'
            });
        }
    } else if(args[0] == "!put") {
        const putSheet = async auth => {
            const gsapi = google.sheets({
  version: 'v4',
  auth
});
            let values = [
                [
                    'Chris',
                    'Male',
                    '4. Senior',
                    'FL',
                    'Art',
                    'Baseball'
                ],
            ];
            const resource = {
                values,
            };
            
            gsapi.spreadsheets.values.update({
              spreadsheetId: '$sheetID',
              range: 'sheet1!A5:F5',
              valueInputOption: 'RAW',
              resource: resource,
            }, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    // Handle error
                    console.log(err);
                    client.pushMessage(event.source['userId'], {
                type: 'text',
                text: "There was an error"
            })
                } else {
                    console.log("Updated!");
                    client.pushMessage(event.source['userId'], {
                type: 'text',
                text: "updated the table"
            })
                }
                
            });
            
            
            
        };

        sheetsClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              return;
            }
            putSheet(sheetsClient);
        });
      }
    
    // if message does not start with !
  } else {
    const readSheet = async auth => {
const gsapi = google.sheets({
  version: 'v4',
  auth
});
        const options = {
          spreadsheetId: '$sheetId',
          range: 'sheet1!A2:C2'
        };
        const { data } = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(options);
        console.log(data.values);
        client.pushMessage(event.source['userId'], {
            type: 'text',
            text: JSON.stringify(data.values)
        })
    };

    sheetsClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        readSheet(sheetsClient);
    });
  }
}

exports.app = functions.region('asia-northeast1').https.onRequest(app);
```

I am in Japan so I set the firebase project region to the closest, and also the functions region to the closest available.
I also checked some of the timing it takes to run the program and found the line messages are taking longer than usual to send. Any input would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In your script, it seems that 2 processes with and without Sheets API. About `very slow`, which process is in those 2 processes? And, for example, when the line of `const sheetsClient = ,,,` is moved to the part for using Sheets API, will the process cost of the process without Sheets API be changed? But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: If you want someone to review your code, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to post. Instead, you should post to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).